# Question about isomorphism of multiplicative groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

How to show that $Q^\times(\sqrt{3})$ and $Q^\times(\sqrt{7})$ are isomorphic? I can not see the explicit isomorphism between (for additive groups this was easy to show, but how to do the same for multiplicative)? Any help is welcome.

Comment: Does $Q^x(\sqrt{3})$ mean the group $Q(\sqrt{3})-\{0\}$ under multiplication ?

Comment: Yes, $Q^\times(\sqrt{3})$ means $(Q(\sqrt{3}-{0},\cdot)$.

Comment: OK. I am thinking about it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these fields have class number $1$, so the corresponding rings of integers are UFDs. The unit groups of these rings of integers are infinite cyclic (a generator for the subgroup of positive elements can be constructed e.g. by using continued fractions to solve Pell's equation) times $\mathbb{Z}/2$ (corresponding to sign changes). It follows that by enumerating the primes in each of the rings of integers one gets an isomorphism between the corresponding quotient fields (each of which is a product of a free abelian group with a countable basis by the group of order $2$). Of the top of my head I can't think of a more explicit proof than this.